# Mac Ventura 上の Nginx に同じ LAN 内の端末からアクセスできない

Tags: macos, nginx

M1 Mac(Ventura)にNginxをインストールしました。Safaliにて自分自身から `http://localhost:8080` にアクセスすると正常にデモ画面が表示されるのですが、同じローカルネットワークにつないでいる別のMacから `http://＜IPアドレス＞:8080` とすると、”サーバーに接続できません。ベージ＜IPアドレス＞を開けません。サーバーに接続できません。” となって拒否されます。

ping や sshで M1Macに接続できることは確認しており、Firewallもオフにしてあります。なにか考えられる原因はありますか。すみませんがよろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 「Firewall はオフ」は Nginx を起動している Mac の話でしょうか？ ping や ssh と web アクセス (80) はポートが違うので、ping や ssh が使えるからといって必ずしも web サーバにアクセスできるとは限りません。

Comment: 自分自身のMacから http://＜IPアドレス＞:8080 とすると接続できますか？

Comment: Nginxが稼働しているMacでは接続できます。

Comment: 「Firewall はオフ」は Nginx を起動している Mac のことです。

Answer (score 0):

自分で、解決にはなっていませんがnginx.confにてportを8080から8888に設定変更したら、何故か見えるようになりました。もやもやは残りますがとりあえず使えます。どなたかもし想像できる理由がわかりましたら教えて下さい。